# How to find Index of element from array when array contains number and Brackets in string format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array
`var arr = ['(', '1', 'AND', '2', ')', 'OR', '(', '3', 'AND', '4', ')']`

First I want to find if my array contains a element if have that element then replace it with another string.

I have tried following

```
arr.find(element=>{
  if(element == 1){
  var elementIndex = arr.indexOf(1);
  arr[elementIndex] = "Name = Test";
}
})
```

Here I'm searching for "1" in array. But always give me output as -1.

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: *I'm searching for "1"*: no, you are searching for 1.

Comment: That's not really how you're supposed to use `find`. You might want to consider [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) as it maybe more useful.

Comment: @trincot Yes, I want to search 1 in an array if the array contains 1 then replace it with another string. Could you please provide the solution

Comment: @trincot he used "==", 1 should match "1"

Comment: Sure, but then `indexOf(1)`... There is not much that makes sense in this code.

Comment: @trincot yes that's right I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `map` array function as so:

```
var arr = ['(', '1', 'AND', '2', ')', 'OR', '(', '3', 'AND', '4', ')'];

var newArray = arr.map(el => el === '1' ? 'new_value' : el);
```

will output:

```
[
    "(",
    "new_value",
    "AND",
    "2",
    ")",
    "OR",
    "(",
    "3",
    "AND",
    "4",
    ")"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what trincot said, your if statement is incorrect.
Your if statement is looking for the number 1.
Your array has the **string** "1".

Comment: That's not what my comment was referring to though. This is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = ['(', '1', 'AND', '2', ')', 'OR', '(', '3', 'AND', '4', ')']
        arr.find(element => {
            if (element === '1') {
                var elementIndex = arr.indexOf(element);
                arr[elementIndex] = "Name = Test";
                console.log(elementIndex)
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ["(", "1", "AND", "2", ")", "OR", "(", "3", "AND", "4", ")"];

const idx = arr.findIndex((el) => el === "1");
if (idx > -1) {
  arr[idx] = "Name = Test";
}
```